# Quarkus can't start dev mode with multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, multi-module

I tried setting up a multi module project with quarkus. I setup a parent with 3 child modules that all can be started with the quarkus dev mode. However when I try to start quarkus dev mode in the parent pom I get the Exception that it can not be build since it is not packaged as a jar.

Here is my pom

```
<groupId>at.myname</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>view</module>
    <module>controller</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.10.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>generate-code</goal>
                        <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                            </native.image.path>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>

                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-index</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jandex</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>native</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <skipITs>false</skipITs>
            <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My build output on quarkus dev is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for at.myname:model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 30, column 22
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] backend                                                            [pom]
[INFO] model                                                              [jar]
[INFO] controller                                                         [jar]
[INFO] view                                                               [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< at.myname:backend >----------------------------
[INFO] Building backend 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                      [1/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final:generate-code (default) @ backend ---
[INFO] Type of the artifact is POM, skipping build goal
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final:dev (default-cli) @ backend ---
[INFO] Invoking org.jboss.jandex:jandex-maven-plugin:1.2.2:jandex) @ backend
[INFO] [SKIP] Cannot process fileset in directory: C:\ws\Polar\backend\target\classes. Directory does not exist!
[INFO] Invoking io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final:generate-code-tests) @ backend
[INFO] Type of the artifact is POM, skipping build goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for backend 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] backend ............................................ FAILURE [  0.349 s]
[INFO] model .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] controller ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] view ............................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.034 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-30T12:07:30+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final:dev (default-cli) on project backend: Failed to run: Failed to resolve artifact at.myname:backend:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact at.myname:backend:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It happens to me as well. Cmon Quarkus...

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus Dev mode is a continuous run of your Quarkus application. So, of course, it still needs to run, and if you run the dev mode successfully, you will see that there is a `something-run.jar` running (e.g., with `jps`):

```
$ jps
44482 Jps
44354 test-app-dev.jar
```

POM is not a runnable type, so the expectation of the Quarkus plugin is right.

But I tried to do what you're after out of curiosity. Here is my project - https://github.com/xstefank/quarkus-reproducers/tree/main/quarkus-multimodule.

First, you see that in the parent pom.xml, we can't define the plugins directly, so they are not executed for the parent of type POM. We can use the `<pluginManagement>` section only to define basically plugin configurations and executions like this: https://github.com/xstefank/quarkus-reproducers/blob/main/quarkus-multimodule/pom.xml#L42. You see that I just wrapped the generated `<plugins>` section. Also, we don't need to define dependencies here since we don't pack any executable code in the parent POM module. I kept the properties and the native profile, so they are inherited in children's modules.

Next, we have three modules (`module1`, `module2`, and `module3`) which are the same, so I'll cover only one.

In `module1`'s pom.xml we can see that we need to define the dependencies for this module, without versions which are still inherited from the Quarkus BOM defined in the parent. And we also need to define just the plugin definitions as showed in https://github.com/xstefank/quarkus-reproducers/blob/main/quarkus-multimodule/module1/pom.xml#L35-L53. Notice that all executions and configuration can be omitted since it is picked from the parent's `<pluginManagement>` section.

One more thing, since you plan to run multiple dev modes at the same time, you need to specify different port on which your Quarkus applications Dev modes run - https://github.com/xstefank/quarkus-reproducers/blob/main/quarkus-multimodule/module1/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1 and similarly in different modules https://github.com/xstefank/quarkus-reproducers/blob/main/quarkus-multimodule/module2/src/main/resources/application.properties#L1.

And that's it, now you can run `quarkus dev` or `mvn quarkus:dev` from the parent module and it runs all the children in dev mode. BUT, since maven execution is sequential, you will first run `module1` dev mode, and it stops there. Only when you stop this dev mode (Ctrl + C) it will run `module2` dev mode, and again only you stop this one, it will run the `module3` dev mode.

But this is how maven works. So what you need is to parallelize the maven execution and luckily this can be done with maven daemon or `mvnd` (https://github.com/apache/maven-mvnd). With this you can do the following in the parent directory:

```
$ mvnd quarkus:dev      
Building quarkus-multimodule  daemon: b580640b  threads used/hidden/max: 3/0/3  progress: 1/4  25%  time
:module3             quarkus:3.3.3:dev (default-cli)
:module2             quarkus:3.3.3:dev (default-cli)                                                    
:module1             quarkus:3.3.3:dev (default-cli)
```

And you have 3 running Quarkus dev modes on three different ports:

```
$ jps
48565 Jps
47959 module3-dev.jar
48122 module2-dev.jar
48062 module1-dev.jar
```

BUT, of course, you don't have access to the individual features of the Dev mode, like the terminal console. For that, you would need to write your own wrapper around the quarkus dev executions, e.g., with a bash script that would run the process in the background.

Hopefully, this helps. If you don't miss the features in the terminal, you can access most of them in the Dev UI. Just remember to be in the correct Dev UI on the correct port of the module you're changing, e.g., http://localhost:8082/q/dev-ui/extensions.